# SQL Left Join using COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

My query is so close, i've gone through almost all the other times this has been posted, but I'm not quite there.

```
SELECT a.name, IFNULL(b.student_id, 0) AS count 
FROM student AS a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  student_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM quizactivity GROUP BY  student_id) 
AS b 
ON a.id = b.student_id;
```

This returns a table with the names of the four entries, and then their actual id on their own table, a.id.

```
Name | Count
Will   1
Jane   2
Sally   0
Dave   4
```

Sally returns 0 because she has no results.
I am cleary returning the id of the table instead of the counts - where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you want the count?

```
SELECT a.name, COALESCE(b.count, 0) AS count 
FROM student a LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT student_id, COUNT(*) as count
      FROM quizactivity
      GROUP BY  student_id
    ) b 
    ON a.id = b.student_id;
```

Comment: `coalesce()` is just the ANSI standard version of `ISNULL()`.  Either can be used, although `coalesce()` is more general because it accepts more than two arguments (returning the first non-`NULL` value).